# Structural Equation Modeling (SEM) across different time periods

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, path-model

I am using SAS to fit SEM to cross-sectional data from 2015. My
theoretical model fits well with the data. Because I also have data
from 2005 onward, I was thinking to fit the model with 2005 and 2010
data (all cross-sectional) and see how the goodness-of-fit indices,
factor loadings and path coefficients change. I would also like to see
whether those changes are (statistically) significant. I looked for
literature on this, but could not find anything. Does this makes
sense, and are there ways to do this? Or, is this something that is
not feasible and/or not interpretable?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would think of this as a two-group model where you're examining measurement and structural (non)invariance, which is certainly a sensible question to answer with SEM.

How the fit indices change isn't really something interpretable, but the rest is testable in a multi-group SEM. I recommend starting with the measurement model: a CFA in each group and testing the loadings, intercepts, etc., for noninvariance. Gordon Cheung has written quite a lot on this process. If metric invariance holds (equal path loadings) then you can confidently move on to testing structural invariance (differences in path coefficients).

Comment: Thanks! I will look into papers by Gordon Cheung. I have one additional question. I am using Maximum Likelihood in proc calis (in SAS) for my analysis. All my variables are categorical (either binary or ordinal). Is ML robust enough for categorical variables in SEM? Or, do I need to use polychoric correlation matrix as my input dataset for the analysis (I have used my raw dataset as an input dataset for the analysis so far). Thank you!

Comment: I would say not to use ML. Polychoric can work with CALIS, but you need to be sure to specify that you are analyzing a correlation matrix rather than the default of a covariance matrix. It's been too long since I used CALIS to be more specific about how to do that.

A better option would be a weighted least squares estimator, if you have sufficient sample size. WLS or DWLS.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like a multiple group design. Is there any way to match the participants between 2005 and 2010, or are they different people?

Comment: Those are cross-sectional samples, but they come from the same population. Individuals are different, though. I guess I can adjust for difference in socio-demographics in SEM.